# Problems after dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I recently install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop alongside windows 10.After installing Ubuntu, I encounter the following problem.

Whenever I start the laptop, I do not get the option to choose windows and Ubuntu and Windows screen appears directly. I have to restart the Windows by pressing Shift + Restart and then do the following.

i.On the choose an option menu I click on Use a device and then choose Ubuntu. After that only the option to open Ubuntu comes up.

[Choose an option menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOr9d.jpg) [Use a device menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksC5O.jpg)

How should  I correct this, so that I can choose the option from windows & Ubuntu at the time of starting laptop only?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Then both should be in same menu. When one is BIOS and other UEFI, then you have to go thru more screens to have correct boot mode to match install. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change where the boot loader is in your BIOS settings. This will be different based on the machine, but generally there will be a "Boot Options" tab or menu in the BIOS settings, and in there you can specify the boot device or boot device order - specify the boot partition (or UEFI image) of your Ubuntu installation or whatever drive/partition GRUB is installed on.